# Count companies which has their various department in the same list

Tags: python

I get to count a [company_names_list_json file](https://heropublic.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/companies_raw_data.json)
 which not only have simple duplicates but also some like:

```
FooTechDepartment
FooFinaceDepartment
BarCompany
BarCompanySalesDepartment
```

I firstly distinct it with set()

```
with open(json_file_name) as f_in:
    companies_raw_data = json.load(f_in)
#distinct the companis 
companies = set(companies_raw_data)
companies = sorted(list(companies))
```

The companies:

```
In [212]: len(companies)
Out[212]: 472
In [227]: companies[40:50]
Out[227]: 
['SpeedyCloud研发中心',
 'SpeedyCloud研发部',
 'The ONE',
 'The ONE产品研发',
 'The ONE产品研发部',
 'TransferEasy',
 'VIPKID',
 'Weego Travel技术',
 'ZingFront智线',
 'ZingFront智线技术部']
```

My idea is to count their length from 1 to max_length,

0, Set a counter to collect the companies

```
counter = {}
```

1, find the one_letter_companis and delete them

```
In[228]: one_letter_companies = [c for c in companies if len(c) == 1]
In[229]: len(one_letter_companies)
Out[229]: 0
```

2, find two_letters_companies and delete them after being collected

```
In[230]: two_letters_companies = [c for c in companies if len(c) == 2]
In[231]: len(two_letters_companies)
Out[231]: 16
```

add them to counter

```
In[238]: for company in two_letters_companies:
     ...:     value = [c for c in companies if c.startswith(company)]
     ...:     counter[company] = value
     ...: for v in value:
     ...:         companies.remove(v)
```

It displays:

```
In[239]: counter
Out[239]:
{'互拍': ['互拍'],
 '博飞': ['博飞'],
 '城宿': ['城宿'],
 '小米': ['小米', '小米小米安全', '小米小米电视'],
 '币信': ['币信', '币信开发部'],
 '库神': ['库神', '库神技术部'],
 '微创': ['微创', '微创ITO', '微创ITO事业部', '微创微创赴微软', '微创赴微软小冰'],
 '掌控': ['掌控', '掌控移动研发'],
 '汇游': ['汇游'],
 '百度': ['百度', '百度百度度秘事业部', '百度视频'],
 '知乎': ['知乎', '知乎商业广告事业部', '知乎工程效率组', '知乎知识市场', '知乎社区平台部'],
 '知藏': ['知藏'],
 '纽曼': ['纽曼'],
 '维朗': ['维朗'],
 '艺恩': ['艺恩'],
 '贝壳': ['贝壳']}
```

The complete codes:

```
counter = {}
while companies:
    #separate the one_letter_companies
    one_letter_companies = [c for c in companies if len(c) == 1]
    if one_letter_companies:
        counter["one_letter_companies"] = one_letter_companies
        for c in one_letter_companies:
            companies.remove(c)

    #handle the companies whose name with more than 1 letter
    #find the max_length 
    max_len = max([len(c) for c in companies]) + 1
    for i in range(2,max_len):
        n_letters_companies = [c for c in companies if len(c)==i]

        if n_letters_companies:
            for company in n_letters_companies:
                value = [c for c in companies if c.startswith(company)]
                counter[company] = value
                #delete the found companied from the companies list
                for v in value:
                    companies.remove(v)
```

It output:

```
In [259]: len(counter)
Out[259]: 391  #vs 472 in the set()
```

I am getting to learn algorithms and also desire dig deep into python.

Could you please offer any hint to solve the problem in an appropriate algorithms or python libs?

Comment: So you solved it? What's your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve it. The key part is sorting the list by *length* so a department will always come after it's company so we can add companies to the results dict before encountering any of their departments. We can then look through the companies to see if any is the company of our current company (or department) and add it to that entry if it is a department, or add it as a key if it is the company.

```
with open(json_file_name) as f_in:
    companies_raw_data = json.load(f_in)

companies = sorted(set(companies_raw_data), key=len)

results = {}
for company in companies:
    for key in results:
        if company.startswith(key):  # is a department
             results[key].append(company)
             break
    else:  # no break -- is not a department
        results[company] = []
```

It's probably more efficient, but less obvious, if you make the loop this instead:

```
results = {}
for company in companies:
    for i in range(len(company) - 1, 0, -1):
        key = company[:i]  # substring
        if key in results:
             results[key].append(company)
             break
    else:  # no break -- is not a department
        results[company] = []
```

Comment: 1) sorted return a list 2) learn to handle empty dict 3) for else 4) break is very trick it takes time to wrap around 5) range(end,start,-1)  6)the second solution for reference, use it 5 for 6 years later.

Comment: @Painter What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: I get "else" finally.  else is a if in its nature, means "if for clause is completed or the clause is not run at all" or "if for clause is not partially run, do the else"

Comment: @Painter yes it is confusing, even in english. People say that a better term would have been `for: ... nobreak: ...`